# what is difference remove_reference or without it

Tags: c++, rvalue

i wrote a simple function that return object rvalue reference.But its not working right.But if i use std::move its working , i see only difference is remove_reference or what is? or my casting to rvalue is wrong ?

```
template<class T>
T&& mymove(T &&obj)
{
    return (T&&)obj;
}
```

---

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&
        move(_Ty&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // forward _Arg as movable
    return ((typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&)_Arg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got in `mymove` is universal reference - not rvalue.

The rule of reference collapsing is this :

```
T&& -> T&&
T&& & -> T&
T& && -> T&
T&& && -> T&&
```

If you pass a lvalue to `mymove`, you are going to get lvalues both as argument and return type. That is why your `mymove` is not working in the same way as `std::move` works.